# Prevent internal location changes of iframe from affecting browser history

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe, browser-history

Note: There are many questions asked where the poster is writing a new location into the iframe from the outside, and is told to use location.replace. This is not what is going on in my case.

Edit: I left my initial description in below, but I decided to describe the issue again in simpler terms.
If I do not have any control over the location change of an iframe, so I cannot use location.replace, how to I stop the iframe from touching the history of the browser?

Original description:
My web application is running an angular app in an iframe. User behavior in this angular app often causes new locations to be written to the iframe, which apparently cascades up and adds new items to the browser history. Is there a way to block the iframe from affecting the outer browser in this way, so the history is not touched at all by the inner angular application?

Comment: Can you provide an example? I'm not seeing how code inside the iFrame is affecting code outside the iFrame, but maybe you're using the postMessage function?

Comment: I'm not sure this is specific enough, but the app running in the iframe uses the angular router to navigate to a new page when the user interacts with the UI. Just clicking on UI elements that take you to new pages within the app. When the router is used to navigate to a new page, the location of the iframe is updated.

It seems to me that it is some built in behavior of the iframe that any changes to its location is cascaded up to the browser. So as far as I understand, my issue is agnostic as to what is running inside the iframe.

Comment: _"It seems to me that it is some built in behavior of the iframe that any changes to its location is cascaded up to the browser."_ - yes, that is how browsers behave regarding navigation in (i)frames. Clicking the back button is supposed to bring the user back to the previous state - and if a change happened only inside an iframe, then going back one position in the history has to revert that change inside the iframe only. I don't think you can do anything about this, _other_ than making the application inside the iframe behave differently to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

The sandbox attribute of the iframe may solve this problem.
Using the sample program of Angular router for testing. As long as the sandbox only sets allow-scripts, the iframe will not affect the navigation of the browser.

```
<iframe src="your url" sandbox="allow-scripts"></iframe>
```

Comment: THANK YOU!

I don't know why all my googling never lead to the sandbox attribute. I'm dead.

Comment: Hmm while I think the sandbox attribute is a good tool to know about, after a bunch of testing it didn't seem to fix the problem for my case.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the problem? Using the sandbox attribute of the iframe, for the angular router example program, testing locally can prevent it from affecting the history of external pages. If it affects other functions on the page, you can add some other attributes of the sandbox, such as allow-forms or others.